# String comparison expression failing in Mapserver when including fieldname

Tags: mapserver

Within classes I'm able to match strings using CLASSITEM, but not when including the field name in the expression, for example (inside a layer declaration):

```
CLASSITEM "myfieldname"
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "sometext"
END
```

Works fine, but

```
CLASS
    EXPRESSION ([myfieldname] = "sometext")
END
```

Doesn't return any data

The second method is fine when working with integers, e.g.

```
CLASS
    EXPRESSION ([myintegerfieldname] = 10)
END
```

I've tried enclosing the strings with single quotes, double quotes, using a regex instead. The same behaviour occurs when the source data is a shapefile or a postgis layer.

Using CLASSITEM is obviously a good work-around, but it would be useful to know what I'm doing wrong with the direct comparison.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CLASS
   EXPRESSION ("[myfieldname]" = "sometext")
END
```

this should force mapserver to use the string equality operator on both fields and explains why it does work with numbers.